# I want to access a general struct field inside another struct's field in C

Tags: c, struct, enums

I have a struct defined like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char id[20];
    char descrizione[250];
    char tipoSet[30];
    int scatoleDisponibili;
    float costo;
} Set;
```

I have another struct called Complex in which I want a field to store an array of only Set struct IDs.

```
typedef struct {
    char idComplesso[20];
    content[10];
    int dimLogica;
} complex;
```

So, I want the content array (of max size 10) to be able to store **only** the string id from a max of 10 Set.

How could I do this in C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
typedef struct {
    char id[20];
    char descrizione[250];
    char tipoSet[30];
    int scatoleDisponibili;
    float costo;
} Set;

typedef struct {
    char idComplesso[20];
    int dimLogica;
    size_t nsets;
    char *content[];
} complex;
```

```
complex *assign(Set *s, size_t nsets)
{
    complex *cml = malloc(sizeof(*cml) + nsets * sizeof(cml -> content[0]));

    /* allocation check */

    cml -> nsets = nsets;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < nsets; i++)
    {
        cml -> content[i] = s[i].id;
    }
    return cml;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to make the content array be an array of char* and when you create the structure only accept id from a Set struct.
Something like this:

```
complex* createComplex(Set* sets) {
  complex* comp = (complex*)malloc(sizeof(complex));
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    comp->content[i] = sets[i].id;
  }
  return comp;
}
```

And don't let any other function create the comp struct